# Firefox snap instead of default deb or flatpak

Tags: firefox, camera

Decided to install the freshly minted eOS 7 today, super impressed by it all till I tried to install firefox as the Gnome Web simply does not cut it as a daily driver for my browser needs.

I was quite surprised to see it installs the snap version, Did I miss something? I though eOS is a flatpak based distro?

Is this correct?

Comment: me sucede lo mismo ,recien instale elementary 7 y al instalar firefox me instala por defecto la versión snapd, alguien ya soluciono este problema ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it has to do with Ubuntu's repo for Firefox forcing snap and not with ElementaryOS. Here's how to add a Firefox repo and install it using apt:

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Thanks, seems I will have to do this, such a shame that they would ship eOS 7 which looks amazing, yet they missed the Firefox issue. Thaks for the link, I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you had to install and enable snapd in Elementary

(at least I had to in EOS6 before I could use snap apps)

https://snapcraft.io/install/snapd/elementary

Haven't found anything saying that it has changed for EOS7 ?

Comment: Bambuko, I dont want snaps at all, its one of the reasons why I love Elementary OS as it come baked with flatpak, in eOS 6.1 still firefox would be installed as a deb and not a snap. This is why I was so surprised when it happened